# HTML::link doesn't point to the right website

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this:

```
{!! HTML::link($item->website, $item->website) !!}
```

`$item->website` is the website inserted by the user. But, if the user inserts something like `www.mysite.com` the result is `localhost:8000/www.mysite.com`
If in database I put `http://` in front of the website,  I get the right result.
Is there any other way than `HTML::link` to properly show the links ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a full URL to the HTML::link(); method, else Laravel will automatically prepend the URL with your local website root. In your case you have to add http:// to your variable and pass the whole URL to the method link();

Check this link ;)
http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/186/generating-a-html-link

Answer (score 1):

`HTML::link()` expects the first parameter to be a relative path in the current site, or a [fully qualified domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name). You need to check if `$item->website` starts with `"http"` and if it doesn't, then prepend it to the string.

```php
<?php $prepend = (strpos($this->website, "http") === 0) ? "" : "http://"; ?>

{!! HTML::link($prepend.$this->website, $this->website) !!}
```

Notice that I'm checking for `"http"` instead of `"http://"`. This allows `"https"` websites to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Url has to be start with "http://".
If user input does not start with it, then you have to add.

Comment: thank you for your answers... i have some extra work to do in any case